# Chaining omit with password_hash() filter

Tags: jinja2, ansible-template

I want to create users, but be able to omit the password for existing users.
The password_hash() filter is giving me some trouble when trying to chain it with omit.

The method with OR is from the ansible documenation.
[Docu](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional)

```
- name: "Ensure users exist"
  user:
    name: "{{item.name}}"
    password: "{{ item.pampass | default(None) | password_hash('sha512') or omit }}"
    groups: "{{item.groups | default(omit) }}"
    state: present
    append: yes
    shell: /bin/bash
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

This gives me:

```
"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ item.pampass | default(None) | password_hash('sha512') or omit }}): secret must be unicode or bytes, not None"
```

I also tried this:

```
password: "{{ item.pampass | default(omit) | password_hash('sha512')  }}"
```

This doesnt fail, but seems to hash an empty string and lock me out of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Now it works.
It sets a password when provided in VARS and doesnt touch it,
when the variable is not defined in VARS

default(omit) defines the variable with a placeholder,
so you cant chain it with the password_hash() filter.
Same thing with default(none).

Code is a little longer, more explicit but works as expcted

```
- name: "Ensure users exists"
  user:
    name: "{{item.name}}"
    password: "{{ item.pampass | password_hash('sha512') if (item.pampass is defined) else omit}}"
    groups: "{{item.groups | default(omit) }}"
    state: present
    append: yes
    shell: /bin/bash
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

You can make it idempotent, by adding a consistent salt (here 'ndqui7Ywog6/hk') to the password_hash() filter.

```
- name: "Ensure users exists"
  user:
    name: "{{item.name}}"
    password: "{{ item.pampass | password_hash('sha512','ndqui7Ywog6/hk') if (item.pampass is defined) else omit}}"
    groups: "{{item.groups | default(omit) }}"
    state: present
    append: yes
    shell: /bin/bash
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```